# Custom Refiners Appear Empty

Tags: 2013, search, refiner, refinement-panel

I have multiple site collections filled with documents. One site collection only hosts the search center (no documents here).

On every site collection (except the search site), the same site columns exist, e.g. 'Project Partner'.

Now I want to introduce refiners. I mapped the column 'Project_x0020_Partner' to RefinableString00 and added it to the refinement web part. However, the refiner is not appearing although the displayed documents in the search results contain the information. Also: When I add RefinableString00 to my web part, instead of displaying some examples it is telling me that the refiner is empty.

I tried this with several other site columns, but without any good result. I assume that the mapping is wrong (hence no examples).

Does anybody have an idea?